# How to replace symbols in some part of string

Tags: java, replace

I've got my SQL script

```
INSERT INTO("TEST1", "TEST2") VALUES("TEST3", "TEST4");
```

I need to replace doublequotes only in TEST1 and TEST2. Out must be look like

```
INSERT INTO('TEST1', 'TEST2') VALUES("TEST3", "TEST4");
```

Is it possible to do it?
**UPDATE:** 
How to do it?

Comment: @StefanWarminski, check update

Comment: Have a look at `String`'s API (keyword replace)

Comment: @SteveSmith pls, check my question, It will replace me all doublequotes but I need to change them only in INTO section.

Comment: @SteveSmith He just wants to replace the quotes in the first part of the string (up to "VALUES"). That being said, this strongly smells to me like someone not using prepared statements when they should...

Comment: @SteveSmith man, I have got a situation when I'm generating sql script but it doesn't work with doublequotes in field-names.

Comment: @Serg, It was just a pointer to help you, not a complete answer.  Why do you even want apostrophes in the field names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple **(P.S. corner case not considered)**

1. Split String (first Part ==> from Insert upto Values
2. Replace first Part
3. Combine firstPart and remaining part

Please try below code:

```
String inputQry = "INSERT INTO(\"TEST1\", \"TEST2\") VALUES(\"TEST3\", \"TEST4\");";

Integer indexOfValuesClause = inputQry.indexOf("VALUES"); // index where VALUES start
String firstPart = inputQry.substring(0,indexOfValuesClause); // first part contains String upto VALUES clause
firstPart = firstPart.replace("\"","'");
System.out.println(firstPart+inputQry.substring(indexOfValuesClause));
```

**Result**

> INSERT INTO('TEST1', 'TEST2') VALUES("TEST3", "TEST4");

Comment: Thank you bro. The Best answer from all. Because some people didn't understand my question and started to minus it. 
Thanx one more!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with replaceAll method from String and appropriate regular expression. The following code replaces all `"` inside first brackets:

```
String sqlCmd = "INSERT INTO(\"TEST1\", \"TEST2\") VALUES(\"TEST3\", \"TEST4\")";
sqlCmd = sqlCmd.replaceAll("(^[^\\(]*\\(|\\G,\\s*)\"([^\"]+)\"", "$1'$2'"); //result INSERT INTO('TEST1', 'TEST2') VALUES("TEST3", "TEST4")
```